# How can I show the visual effect of a pressed button when I press another button?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two buttons. How to show the visual effect of clicking both buttons, actually pressing only one of them?

Comment: what effect you want to show ?  What have you tried ? Add your code.

Comment: I want to show the pressing of both buttons by clicking on only one of them.

Comment: @Ragnaroker until now what have done ad where are u struck?? please post ur code

Comment: The standard effect of pressing. If you click on the first button, it shows that both buttons were pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show effects on button press and button release, you can use this code.

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                button2.setPressed(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                button2.setPressed(false);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is it! This solves the problem with a delay from the @B.M answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want only the animation effect you can try this :

```
buttonLeft = findViewById(R.id.left);
buttonRight = findViewById(R.id.right);

buttonLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    buttonRight.setPressed(true);
                    buttonRight.setPressed(false);

                }
            });

        }
```

It's working, but maybe there's a better way to this,
Hope it will help

Comment: he wants to show effect like  both buttons have been clicked

Comment: @B.M Yes, this is exactly what I need! Thank you! I tried performClick(). But this does not display the click effect.

Is there some kind of standard delay that could be between setPressed(true) and setPressed(false)?